# How to read from stdin with fgets()?

Tags: c, stdin, fgets, feof

My professor write a C code about fgets,feof with using stdin.
But I don't understand how it works.

```
fgets(list, 100, stdin);

while (!feof(stdin))
{
    printf("feof!");
    
    fgets(list, 100, stdin);
}
```

when i write a 'hello', function while is working.
why feof(stdin) returns 0?

I think first fgets read stdin buffer all of string(include '\0').
therefore I think while shouldn't work because feof(stdin) returns 1
What am i wrong?

Comment: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: And [`feof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) returns "true" (non-zero) when the input file reaches the end. For terminal input through `stdin` that happens when you press the end-of-file keyboard sequence (`Ctrl-D` on Linux or macOS, `Ctrl-Z` on a new line in Windows).

Comment: "fgets read stdin buffer all of string(include '\0')" --> No.  `fgets()` reads a _line_ (characters up to and including a `'\n'`), saves that to the buffer and then appends a `'\0'`.  Now the buffer is a _string_.

Comment: To make @Someprogrammerdude's comment explicit, your professor's code is wrong.

Comment: Always control your *Read-Loop* with the return from your *Read-Function*... (your professor's implementation is horribly awkward, though not technically incorrect)

Answer (score 1):

Tip: always check the return value of input functions and most other I/O functions too.

```
fgets(list, 100, stdin);  // Weak code
```

---

Yes, calling `printf("feof!");` inside the  loop is misleading as the end-of-file indicator for `stdin` is not set given the prior test condition `while (!feof(stdin))`.

> How to read from stdin with fgets()?

**Do not use `feof()` for this task for primary detection**

`fgets()` returns `NULL` when:

1. An end-of-file just occurred in the previous input operation.
2. An end-of-file had occurred in the some input operations even before that.
3. An input error just occurred.  Examples: file to read is an output stream or a parity error on some serial communication.

`while (!feof(stdin))` only detects 1 & 2.

Unless the return value of `fgets(list, 100, stdin)` is checked, using `list` may be a problem.

`feof()` is useful *after* an I/O function returned the possibility of the need.

**Size to the object, avoid magic numbers**

---

Good usage:

```
char list[100];
while (fgets(list, sizeof list, stdin)) {
  printf("%s", list):
}

if (feof(stdin)) {
  puts("End-of-file");
} else if (ferror(stdin)) {
  puts("Error");
} else {
  puts("Unexpected state");
}
```

Comment: Always very informative and complete. Too bad we can "pop" this back into the text-books on the subject.